# How do I add event categories to the Calendar in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

When adding an event to the board calendar in Azure DevOps there is a dropdown for Category. Currently there are no options available in that dropdown and I can't figure out how to create categories to group events under.

I've looked under our project settings and tried searching on Google and here, but I can't find an answer to this question.

My goal is to create categories for our production support monitoring and automated test result monitoring. Team members alternate each week on who is monitoring what and I'd like to add whose week it is to monitor and categorize it accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no page to add categories for this extension [Team Calendar](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.team-calendar). You just create a new event and type a new category name. Then the list of categories will be based on all values of the category field. If you want to remove some category, you have to remove all events of that category.

here you may find the source code: https://github.com/microsoft/vsts-team-calendar/